# How to use .so file in Xposed module project?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, xposed-framework, xposed

How to turn this Hello-JNI project https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0
to an Xposed module and use method "getMsgFromJni" inside hooking methods?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if Xposed already supports this feature but it should be possible to place the .so in the apps native libraries folder or perhaps hook Android's DexClassLoader to load your library.

I have successfully loaded .so files into other apps using a class loader. My solution can be a nice use case so you can find how to make it do what you want. Basically I placed the libraries in /data/local/tmp/natives and then did something like:

```
//JNI classes are in data/local/tmp/dexjars/
File[] files = new File("data/local/tmp/dexjars/" + type + "/").listFiles();

//Folder to store optimized dex code
String hash = "dex" + lpparam.packageName.hashCode();

//In case you want to have several packages to load
for (File file : files) {

    final File tmpDir = new File("data/local/tmp/optdexjars/" + hash + "/");

    tmpDir.mkdirs();

    //Create a DexClassLoader that links yo your native libraries   
    final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(
                        file.getAbsolutePath(), tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "data/local/tmp/natives/",
                        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

    //Retrieve your classes performing the JNI
    Class c = Class.forName("FULLY_QUALIFIED_JNI_CLASSNAME", true, classloader);
}
```

If you need some details on how to package your functionality take a look [here](http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2015/01/27/how-to-easy-way-load-apk-classes-using-dexclassloader/).

If you find how to do it in a easier way please do post.

Good luck!